# Show that the following function is continuous but not differentiable at $x=1.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the function 
>   $$f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> |2x-3|[x] & \text{if} \ x\ge1 \\ \\
> \sin\frac{\pi x}{2} &\text{if} \ x\lt1 \ 
> \end{cases}.
> $$
>   is continuous but not differentiable at $x=1.$

I tried to solve it like this:
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(2x-3)[x] & \text{if} \ x\ge\frac{3}{2} \\ \\
-(2x-3) & \text{if} \ 1\le x\lt\frac{3}{2} \\ \\
\sin\frac{\pi x}{2} &\text{if} \ x\lt1 \ 
\end{cases}.$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=-2+3=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=1$$
$$f(1)=1$$
Therefore the function is continuous since the above are equal.
Now,
$$L.H.D.=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{1-h-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi (1-h)}{2}-1}{-h}=???$$
and
$$R.H.D.=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{1+h-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{h}=???$$
*L.H.D. is Left Hand Derivative and R.H.D. is Right Hand Derivative*
Can you help me with this?
Thankyou.

Comment: Before the first ??? part, it should read: $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0 ^ {\color{red}{+}}} \frac{\sin \left( \frac{\pi (\color{red}{(1 - h)})}{2} \right) - 1}{-h}$ Can you find that limit as $h$ tends to $0^ {+}$? And btw, when proving some function is continuous at 1, you should point out that the left limit is equal to the right limit, and both of them should be equal to f(1). You forget the last step.

Comment: Sorry I will edit the first part. I had accidentally omitted $f(1)$ and I will edit that. But that is not my question. So there shouldnt be any problem. Thanks  +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a small $\,\epsilon>0\,$ , then:

$$x\in [1,1+\epsilon]\implies |f(x)-f(1)|=|(3-2x)-1|=2(x-1)\xrightarrow[x\to 1^+]{}0$$

$$x\in[1,1-\epsilon]\implies |f(x)-f(1)|=\left|\sin\frac{\pi x}2-1\right|\xrightarrow[x\to 1^-]{}0$$

The above proves continuity at $\,x=1\,$ . About differentiability:

$$f'_+(1):=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{2(x-1)}{x-1}=2$$

$$f'_-(1):=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}2-1}{x-1}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\;\frac{\pi}2\cos\frac{\pi x}2=0$$

and since the one-sided derivatives at $\,x=1\,$ exist *but* are different the functions isn't derviable there.

Comment: What is Hospital?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Comment: thnx I understood  ...    +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the derivative and compare the left and right limits at $x=\frac{3}{2}$. Here is the derivative:
$$
f^{\prime}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
4x-3 & \frac{3}{2}<x\\
? & x=\frac{3}{2}\\
-4x+3 & 1<x<\frac{3}{2}\\
? & x=1\\
\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right) & x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now do the same thing for $x=1$.